# Why does Clang’s -Wrange-loop-analysis warn at a for loop with a std::string_view variable? Isn’t std::string_view a reference?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, string-view

I have this loop:

```
for (const std::string_view resource : resources) { ... }
```

whereby resources is defined as

```
inline const std::string_view resources[] = { ... }
```

But I get this error:

> error: loop variable '`resource`' of type '`const std::string_view`' (aka '`const basic_string_view<char>`') creates a copy from type '`const std::string_view`' [`-Werror`,`-Wrange-loop-analysis`]

Why is that. I thought `std::string_view` was just a reference to the actual data. But here it's copied instead?

Comment: `string_view` is indeed copied, but it doesn't copy underlying string.

Comment: You want a reference, then use a reference: `for (const std::string_view& resource : resources) { ... }`

Comment: Cannot reproduce the warning [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a9P883Wza), which version of clang do you use?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is that.

You make a copy because the loop variable is not a reference (and has the same type as the element).

> I thought std::string_view was just a reference to the actual data.

That's what it is conceptually. More specifically, it is a class that contains a pointer to the data, and the size (or alternatively, pointer to the end; it doesn't matter). You make a copy of this conceptual "reference" i.e. that class instance.

---

Note that `-Wrange-loop-analysis` is not enabled by default nor by `-Wall` nor by `-Wextra` (at least in Clang 9). Such "warnings" often don't necessarily imply that there is anything wrong with the program. They may be either informative hints, or they may have high rate of false positives.

Clang no longer produces the warning for the given example since version 10. This is what the release notes say:

> -Wrange-loop-analysis got several improvements. ... It no longer warns when an object of a small, trivially copyable type is copied.

So, my suggested solution is to upgrade your compiler and/or don't explicitly enable `-Wrange-loop-analysis`.

Answer (score 2):

`string_view` is a wrapper for a pointer to a string and its size.  When you do:

```
for (const std::string_view resource : resources)
```

You are copying those variables, so you get a warning.  The string is not being copied, but there is some non-zero amount of data being copied.

If you used a refererence like:

```
for (const std::string_view& resource : resources)
```

Then even the pointer and size members will no longer be copied.

Comment: But this add extra indirections ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Does it?  Shouldn't the compiler elide that away and work directly with the source?

Comment: `const std::string_view&` looks weird and it should: you're using a constant reference to a reference variable. I don't like this usage just to appease the compiler.

Comment: @PasserBy That's a matter of perspective. To me, a range based for loop with a reference type just means "the element in the container" as opposed to "an element like the one in the container" and appears more correct to me. Specially when the reference is to `const`, I would be confident nothing strange is intended or happening.

Comment: @PasserBy You can fix that by using `const auto& resource : resources` ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It should be `const auto&` in that case. Wouldn't you find `int* const &` weird? Or maybe `const std::unique_ptr<int>&`.

Comment: @Jarod42 The assembly instructions are likely to be the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not sure indeed, especially after optimization.

Comment: @PasserBy I agree this would be better with `auto`. But if you are concerned about a reference to `string_view` you should be equally concerned if `auto` was used. Regarding `std::unique_ptr` you usually *have* to use a reference since it is not copyable. So it is not weird at all.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't mean the semantics are wrong, they're obviously correct. I mean the syntax rings alarms. When you write the type explicitly instead of just `auto`, it usually means something. I will certainly check if I read correctly whenever I see `const std::unique_ptr<int>&` instead of `int*`. The former has zero benefits over the latter but you start questioning yourself about extra indirections (as evidently seen).

Comment: @PasserBy My argument is that the version with reference is not factually more concerning, but that it is a matter of opinion, and we differ on that opinion. Secondly, using `unique_ptr` is a poor example since `unique_ptr<int>` and `int*` are not comparable in this context, they accomplish very different things. If you have a container of `std::unique_ptr` you **have** to use a unique_ptr reference in a range based for loop, since the element is not copyable.

Answer (score 0):

[I just read that the ctor is the copy constructor.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) That explains it.

> 2. Copy constructor. Constructs a view of the same content as other. After construction, `data()` is equal to `other.data()`, and `size()` is equal to `other.size()`.